# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'activityStart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I am facing issues with the Phonegap App when trying to display a progress dialog using

> navigator.notification.activityStart("", "Loading");

Cordova version used is `PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '3.6.4';`

With the index.html file declared in the following way :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>        
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoad() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

//device ready
function onDeviceReady()
{          
   var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");

   if(userId)
   {
       navigator.notification.activityStart("", "Loading");
   }
}
</script>
```

When I run this code on the device, Cordova throws the below error and a blank screen is displayed :

> file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 33 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'activityStart' of undefined

Please suggest me what changes I need to implement with the code.

Comment: The error tells you that `navigator.notification` is `undefined`. So you need to figure out why that is (for instance, have you configured `config.xml` correctly?). But separately, even once you resolve that, I don't see `activityStart` anywhere in the [notification API](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html).

Comment: The original code was written on cordova 2.9.0, and now I am trying to port this in to 3.6.  So you mentioning that there is some changes happened to notification API?

Comment: @ Timson: I have no idea. I just know that I don't see `activityStart` on the API page.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error "Cannot call method 'activityStart' of undefined" since the notification object  may not be available.

Can you confirm whether the notification plugin is installed or not.

To check: 
`cordova plugin ls`

and it should show cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification" in the list. If not you need to install this plugin and try again.
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`

This is was the tips i did for getting my issue fixed.